# Loading of external SWF results in a "Could not find resource bundle messaging" error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I'm using flash.display.Loader to load [this example SWF](http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/ChartSampler/app.html) as a use-case for loading SWFs that uses flex charting components in an application I'm working on.

This is the code I'm using to load the swf:

Main.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event);">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import myLoaderClass;

private function onCreationComplete( e:FlexEvent ):void
{
    trace("Init!");
    var l:myLoaderClass = new myLoaderClass();
    this.addChild(l);
}

]]>
</mx:Script>    
</mx:Application>
```

myLoaderClass:

```
package 
{   
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;



    public class JittRunner extends UIComponent 
    {

        private var displayedObjects:Dictionary;

        public function JittRunner():void 
        {
            displayedObjects = new Dictionary();

            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('ChartSampler.swf');
            mLoader.load(mRequest);         
        }

    }
}
```

The thing is, the minute the swf is loaded I'm getting the following runtime error:

> Error: Could not find resource bundle messaging
>   at mx.resources::ResourceBundle$/getResourceBundle()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\resources\ResourceBundle.as:143]
>   at mx.utils::Translator$cinit()
>   at global$init()
>   at mx.messaging.config::ServerConfig$cinit()
>   at global$init()
>   at _app_FlexInit$/init()
>   at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::docFrameHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:3217]
>   at mx.managers::SystemManager/docFrameListener()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:3069]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're not doing anything wrong in the code you posted. I just pasted it into a new project (renamed `JittRunner` to `myLoaderClass`) and it compiled and ran fine (didn't do anything but no errors).